# How to alter default redirect after Entityform delete

Tags: forms

By default, entityform delete form action is hardcoded in file `entityform.admin.inc` to the following value:

```
$form_state['redirect'] = "admin/structure/entityform_types/manage/{$entityform->type}/submissions";
```

As this function is a submit callback, it is executed AFTER invoking hook form alter, so this approach won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add another submit callback. This one will run after the one Entityform uses for the redirect. This way, we will be able to overwrite that hardcoded value:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()
 * Makes sure it redirects to results on Delete.
 */
function MYMODULE_form_entityform_delete_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#submit'][] = '_MYMODULE_form_delete_redirect';
}

function _MYMODULE_form_delete_redirect($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'MY_REDIRECT';
}
```